# stack 1.6.5 not working with cabal 2.0.0.1

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have stack 1.6.5 but see the error described in [Cabal 2.0 required when using a nightly snapshot with stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815830/cabal-2-0-required-when-using-a-nightly-snapshot-with-stack). I understand that the problem was solved in stack v 1.5.1, but I see it in 1.6.5:

```
Using resolver: lts-11.2

Warning: Installed version of cabal-install (2.0.0.1) is newer than stack has been tested with.  If you run into difficulties, consider downgrading.

Using compiler: ghc-8.2.2
Asking cabal to calculate a build plan...
Trying with packages from lts-11.2 and 3 external packages as hard constraints...
The following lines from cabal-install output could not be parsed: 
abstract-par-0.3.3 (via: monad-par-0.3.4.8 monad-par-extras-0.3.3) (new
package)
base-compat-0.9.3 (via: criterion-1.3.0.0 criterion-1.3.0.0 aeson-pretty-0.8.5

aeson-1.2.4.0 quickcheck-instances-0.3.18) (new package)
```

stack upgrade gives:

```
frank@oporto:~/Workspace8/LitTextWork/LitText$ stack upgrade
Current Stack version: 1.6.5, available download version: 1.6.5
Skipping binary upgrade, you are already running the most recent version
```

I assume that the output is harmless, but should be bypassed in this version? How would I downgrad the cabal? What is the last cabal version recommended?

Comment: Being involved with their development, I can only speak on behalf of Cabal and GHC regarding the officially supported configurations: For GHC 8.0, you should use at least `cabal-install-1.24`; for GHC 8.2, you should use at least `cabal-install-2.0`; for GHC 8.4 you need at least `cabal-install-2.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Stack issues [#3453](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3453) and [#3799](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3799) suggest this is a known bug in Stack. Until a fix for it lands, a makeshift workaround [suggested in a comment to #3453](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3453#issuecomment-376247809) is using `stack --resolver lts-9 install cabal-install` to install *cabal-install* 1.24.0.2 (the executable, not the library).

Caveats:

- The workaround assumes the local installation path Stack uses (cf. what `stack path --local-bin` tells you) has priority over the path of the globally installed *cabal-install* in hour `PATH` environment variable, or if you don't have a globally installed *cabal-install* to begin with (e.g. if you aren't using the Haskell Platform).
- [As hvr points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627839/stack-1-6-5-not-working-with-cabal-2-0-0-1#comment86265244_49627839), this is not officially supported as far as Cabal and GHC are concerned, and you might run into further issues if features from newer *cabal-install* versions ever turn out to be necessary while using the solver via Stack.
- If you ever need or want to have an up-to-date *cabal-install*, just use `stack install cabal-install` -- which will do it with the resolver you are using elsewhere. (If you have a globally installed *cabal-install* and want to go back to using it, you can simply delete the Stack-installed one from the location indicated by `stack path --local-bin`.)

Comment: thank you for your information. it seems that the issue is only one of bening error messages, which can be ignored. I had the impression, that the issue was fixed in `stack 1.6.5` but it seems not. I wait for the next version... - @steshaw recommends  "install cabal-install 1.24.0.2 using stack --resolver lts-9 install cabal-install" in <https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3453>

Comment: @user855443 "it seems that the issue is only one of bening error messages" -- That's good to hear. Do you mean the command you run to get the first warning message (the one which says "The following lines from cabal-install output could not be parsed") succeeds? (By the way, it would be useful to know how to reproduce the issue you describe.)

Comment: It happended only once (when I upgraded to LTS 11.2 and never since. I did not *see* any negative effects. If it happens again, I will document.

Comment: I am working on a different computer and here the messages seems to occur consistently when I run `stack solver`. what information would be useful information for you?

Comment: @user855443 Adding the `stack.yaml` and `package.yaml` (and/or the .cabal file) files for your package would help. Ideally, it would be good to have a minimal example that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: i will try to produce a miniaml example next week (the real case is somewhat large) - but only next weekend (during the week i work on another computer).